# Designing DB Table

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to design a database table in which, I have one column for ID (unique) one column for name and another column for a list of integers (3 or sometimes 4 numbers). These numbers are ID of other rows in the same table (Adjacent Rows). What is the best way to design this table?

Sample rows:

```
ID    Name    Adjacent
1     AAA     2,3,14
2     BBB     1,7,26
3     CCC     1
7     DDD     2,26
14    EEE     1
26    FFF     2,7
```

Comment: There, haven't you just designed all of it?

Comment: As I wrote it the third column is a string. I wanted to know if there's a better way to keep these ID's, so that I don't need to parse them in my code

Comment: Some databases have support for array columns. If yours doesn't, then you should move them to a related table (many-to-many relationship, I think)

Answer (score 2):

you may try the sql fiddle below. it is written in t-sql. the detail table `Adjacent` has a many-to-one relationship with the main table `Main`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/becec/2

when you want to query the adjacent data as one row, t-sql has query hints for that.

Comment: Tanx. but you, when 1 is adjacent to 2, 2 is also adjacent to 1. Is there a way that I don't have to add two rows for this relation?

Comment: the many-to-one relationship between tables has been tried and tested by most applications and has been proven to be the optimal design a master-detail scenario. this also allows you to issue simple queries to determine the count of adjacent rows to the main table.